# Calculating run time complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion

I'm new to calculating the run time complexity of algorithms, and am used to working out the complexity usually when an algorithm has a for-loop within it, and am unsure how to correctly calculate the complexity for my algorithm, as it is mainly just a list of many if-statements.

The code can be seen below, and the algorithm tests to see if a String c is an ordered shuffle of Strings a and b.

```
public class StringShuffleTest {

        public static boolean isOrderedShuffle(String a, String b, String c){
            //boolean to determine if String c is an ordered shuffle.
            boolean isShuffled = false;
            //variables for the size of Strings a, b and c.
            int n = a.length();
            int m = b.length();
            int len = c.length();     

            //if the length of c is not the length of a + b return false.
            if (len != (n + m)){
                return isShuffled;
            }

            //if String c contains String b as a substring, then remove String b from c and make m = 0.
            if (c.contains(b)){
                c = c.replace(b, "");
                m = 0;
            }

            //if the length of a or b is 0, and c equals a or b, return true, otherwise,
            //return false.
            if (n == 0 || m == 0){
                if (c.equals(a) || c.equals(b)){
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return isShuffled;
            }

            //if String a has length 1, remove a from String c and make String a empty.
            if (n == 1){
                    c = c.substring(0, c.indexOf(a.charAt(0))) + c.substring(c.indexOf(a.charAt(0)) +1);
                    a = "";
                    return isOrderedShuffle(a, b, c);

                }

            //An ordered shuffle of two given strings, a and b, is a string that can be formed by interspersing
            //the characters of a and b in a way that maintains the left-to-right order of the characters from each
            //string.

            //Recursive algorithm to determine if String c is an ordered shuffle of a and b.
            else
            if (c.indexOf(a.charAt(0)) >= 0){

                int indexOfFirsta = c.indexOf(a.charAt(0));
                int indexOfSeconda = c.indexOf(a.charAt(1));

                if (indexOfFirsta <= indexOfSeconda){
                c = c.substring(0, indexOfFirsta) + c.substring(indexOfFirsta +1);
                a = a.substring(1, n);
                    System.out.println(a);
                    System.out.println(c);                   
                return isOrderedShuffle(a, b, c);
                }

            else
                if (c.indexOf(b.charAt(0)) >= 0){
                        int indexOfFirstb = c.indexOf(b.charAt(0));
                        int indexOfSecondb = c.indexOf(b.charAt(1));

                        if (indexOfFirstb <= indexOfSecondb){
                            c = c.substring(0, indexOfFirstb) + c.substring(indexOfFirstb +1);
                            b = b.substring(1, m);
                            System.out.println(b);
                            System.out.println(c);

                        return isOrderedShuffle(a, b, c);

                    }
            }

            }
        return isShuffled;         
        }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(StringShuffleTest.isOrderedShuffle("cat", "castle", "castlecat")); 

    }

    }
```

I initially feel like the best-case run time complexity should be t(n) = 1, if the first letter of c does not equal the first letter of a or b, and the worst case should be t(n)= n+m, if it has to compare the characters for every letter in String c. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Count if-statments as constant time (unless they call routines/methods which are not) for the purpose of asymptotic complexity bounds.  The complexity of your algo above comes from the fact that it is /recursive/.  You also need to be aware that those `indexOf()` are *not* constant-time...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Would i then be right in thinking that the Best-Case run time complexity for this algorithm would simply be t(n)=1, as one comparison within the if-statement would output false.